# what should i do to ignore sliding/squeeze my view in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

Just to the point, when i run my apps in my device with personal hotspot connection on (appear at top statusbar), the blue bar (personal hotspot connection) is squeezing my view/background. how do i ignore or fix this? Thank you. `i hope you understand what i mean.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option is to hide the status bar permanently or resizing the elements and the background when this happens.